# Bounding rapidly decreasing function by Schwartz function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and suppose that it is rapidly decreasing, i.e. for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}{|x^nf(x)|}<\infty.$$
Can we always find a Schwartz function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f|\le\varphi$?

In other words, can we bound a function that is "zeroth order Schwartz" by a function nice enough to actually be Schwartz?

I was thinking of explicitly constructing such a $\varphi$ by having it match the values of $|f|$ at its maxima, and smoothly interpolating in between, but it is not clear if it would be easy to prove that such a construction is indeed Schwartz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure with $g(x) = \sup_{y \in [x-1,x+1] } |f(y)|$ then $$g \ast \varphi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) \varphi(x-y)dy$$ is Schwartz where $$\varphi(x) = 3 \, e^{-1/(1-x^2)} 1_{|x| < 1} \in C^\infty_c$$

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\varphi} = 0.44$, so some dilation of $\varphi$ may be necessary. But otherwise I think this would work! So to fill in some details to check my understanding of your answer: we have $|f|\le g\ast\varphi$ (if, say, $\int{\varphi}\ge 1$) since $g(y)\ge|f(x)|$ on $[x-1,x+1]$, which is where $\varphi(x-y)$ is supported, while $g\ast\varphi$ is Schwartz since its $k$th derivative is $g\ast\varphi^{(k)}$, which is bounded by $\max_{y\in[x-1,x+1]}{g(y)}\cdot\int{\varphi^{(k)}}$, and the former term decays rapidly because $f$ does as well.

Comment: @JoeyZou Right don't know why I assumed $\int \varphi(x)dx > 1$

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!