# Schwartz function absolute value

Tags: fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $\phi$ be an element of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, the space of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists $\psi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $|\phi|\leq\psi$.

I am not getting any idea on how to prove it. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Does $\psi = \sqrt{1 + |\phi|^2}$ work?

Comment: @Mason, I think it doesn't.  This might not be $\mathscr C^\infty$ and moreover the limit at $\infty$ is 1 rather than zero.

Comment: A cousin question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2444044/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie The problem you link to is actually stronger than OP, so the answer linked is a solution to OP

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: If $\phi$ is Schwartz, $2\phi$ is also Schwartz.